# Debug Firebreath code with Safari Browser

Tags: javascript, c++, .net, firebreath

How to attach the Debug points with the Safari Browser. As I have implemented my application in the Firebreath Framework which supports the unmanaged Code. To verify the Functionality in the Safari Browser as well, I am attaching the Debug Points but Debug Points will not hit. Is it necessary to set any kind of Property for the same . Please Let me know how to attach the Firebreath code with Safari browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that Safari starts your plugin in another process.  If you look at np_macmain.cpp you'll see that there is a define that you can set that will cause it to pause and wait for the debugger to attach -- this is your best option if you need to attach early.  Note that I've seen Safari kill plugins that don't respond soon enough, which tends to lead to your plugin getting killed any time it's stuck in a breakpoint.

see http://www.firebreath.org/display/documentation/Debugging+Plugins -- the Safari stuff is a little out of date, but the concepts are the same.  I think the process name has changed.

Comment: Many thanks for your valuable reply. Now I am easily verify my Applications functionality with Safari Browser as well.